# What can be used to replace Windows authentication in a legacy .NET web application?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, windows-authentication

We have a a bunch of .NET web applications (Web Forms and MVC) that use Windows authentication. We need to get these apps ready to run in AWS Elastic Bean Stalk service but Windows authentication is not supported. I've seen blogs with tricky workarounds to make it work but would prefer to avoid that path.

If we remove Windows authentication from the applications what is a good alternative that we can put in that will still provide users with the same single sign on experience but be directly supported in the new environment?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good option could be [Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/).

The Microsoft Identity accounts could be used as the Windows OS login for the users in their local machines, so it will be the same account used to login to the web applications (also will be a single sign-on experience, as with any OAuth identity implementation).